# Combine several ps/eps figures into one

Tags: postscript, eps

I have several ps/eps figures. They are generated in a time loop, each with the same size. How can I combine them into a single ps/eps file? So I can view all of them in gsview by clicking "next page". I prefer a single file like a.eps, rather than a1.eps, a2.eps......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

`gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=epswrite -sOutputFile=out.eps *.eps`

It should take all the eps files and create a new one called out.eps with all of them in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you